# Types of growth curves that can be compared using statmod compareGrowthCurves

Tags: r, curve-fitting, growth-model, curves

I'm using the function `compareGrowthCurves` in the R package statmod, but I can't seem to find an explanation of what types of curve this is valid for.  Does anyone know if there are particular families of functions I shouldn't use this for?

Specifically, I have data on bacterial growth and under some conditions I have textbook logistic growth to a stable plateau in stationary phase, but in others I have an obvious death phase after the onset of stationary phase.  Will I get valid results with this type of curve? (I am only making comparisons between curves of the same general shape).

Thanks for any info, I'm sure it's out there but I haven't found it.